# Python 2.7 - min built-in function not working as expected

Tags: python, dictionary, min, built-in

I'm making Google Python exercises and don't understand the behaviour of min() built-in function, which seems not to produce the expected result.
The exercise is "babynames", and I'm testing the code with 'baby1990.html' file
(https://developers.google.com/edu/python/exercises/baby-names)

```
def extract_names(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r').read()
    res = []
    d = {}
    match = re.search(r'<h3(.*?)in (\d+)</h3>', f)
    if match:
            res.append(match.group(2))

    vals = re.findall(r'<td>(\d+)</td><td>(\w+)</td><td>(\w+)</td>', f)
    for n, m, f in vals:
            if m=='Adrian' or f=='Adrian':
                    if m not in d:
                            d[m] = n
                    else:
                            d[m] = min(n, d[m])

                    if f not in d:       
                            d[f] = n
                    else:
                            print "min( "+str(n)+", "+str(d[f])+") = "+str( min(n, d[f]) ) 
                            d[f] = min( [n, d[f]] )

    for name,rank in sorted(d.items()):
    res.append(name+" "+str(rank))

    return res
```

vals is a list of tuples (rank, male_name, female_name) and I want to store each name
(male and female) in the dictionary 'd' with name as key and rank as value.
If there's a duplicate, i want to keep the lower rank value.

I noticed that the name 'Adrian' appears two times in the collection, the first time as male name with rank 94 and the second time as female with rank 603, and i want the smaller of the two values.

So, the first time 'Adrian' is matched, it's stored in the dictionary with rank 94 (correctly). When it's matched the second time, the execution flow correctly enters the second branch of the second if, but the result becames 603, even if min(94, 603) = 94.
So the result is:

```
min( 603, 94) = 603
1990
Adrian 603
Anton 603
Ariel 94
```

I don't understand where the bug is. Via interpreter, min(94, 603) = 94, as expected. What am I missing?

Thanks for help

PS: I also tried 
    min( n, d[f] )
that is the same function without list, but the result is always 603

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are comparing strings, **not** numbers:

```
>>> min('603', '94')
'603'
```

Lexographically, `'6'` sorts before `'9'`. Regular expressions work on strings, returned  matches are strings even when digits are matched. Use `int()` to turn your strings into integers:

```
vals = re.findall(r'<td>(\d+)</td><td>(\w+)</td><td>(\w+)</td>', f)
for n, m, f in vals:
    n = int(n)
    # ...
```

When trying to debug Python code, use `repr()` instead of `str()` to detect type problems; had you used `repr()` you would have seen that `'94'` would be printed instead of `94` (so with quotes to denote a string).

Comment: Typo: "has you used `str()` you would ..." should say `repr()` (I'd edit myself, but I'm not keen to find out how well SO handles concurrent edits.)

Comment: @delnan: Ah, should read better and not focus on a typo in your comment. :-P

Comment: Thank you for this fast reply. I would have never found this one! 
But why 603 is int and not string?

Comment: @jsil: `'603'` is a string too; my initial diagnosis was a bit of the mark, I have adjusted my answer since then.

Comment: Great point, and easy to do without explicitly checking the type!